# nginx redirect based on $request_uri

Tags: nginx, request

In my default site config file, I have the following redirect to enforce https :

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com example.com;
    return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
 }
```

I want to add a subdomain, but to redirect it to the site wit a parameter.
e.g.
fr.example.com --> https://example.com?lang=fr

If I do:

```
return       301 https://example.com$request_uri&lang=fr;
```

It will add on '&lang=fr' whether there are any other parameters in **$request_uri** or not.

How do I conditionally define '?' or '&', based on the content of $request_uri ?

I tried the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  fr.example.com;
       if ($request_uri ~ ""){
           return       301 https://example.com?tlang=fr;
       }
        return       301 https://example.com$request_uri&tlang=fr;
}
```

but like this the site failed all-together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `$request_uri` does not contain query arguments for the request.

There are two options:

1. Use a return where you add `$args` after the `lang` argument:

`return 301 https://example.com?lang=fr&$args:`

2. Use a map:

In `http` level, you define the map:

```
map $args $redirargs {
    "~.+" $args&lang=fr;
    default lang=fr;
}
```

And then use

```
return 301 http://example.com$request_uri?$redirargs;
```

Comment: #2 didn't work for me, but #1 works OK.
Just that when there are no other parameters, it looks like this: example.com/?lang=fr&
Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "#2 didn't work for me"? What exactly happened?

Comment: nginx failed to restart

Comment: What was the error message?